# What's wrong with this code? I am getting unusual output

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a=3.14159*22500;
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(4)<<a;
}
```

Output I am getting is 70685.7734 and the actual answer is 70685.7750, how can I modify my code to get the correct output?

Comment: A typical `float` only gives you about 6 or 7 digits of decimal precision. Due to that sparseness, the closest `float` to the true value is selected.

Comment: It's kind of ironic that a question about the accuracy of floating point arithmetic uses a value of `3.14159` for pi.

Comment: You will get better output if you use `double` instead of `float`. But there is no answer to this issue, because many correct answers are simply not representable as floating point values.

Comment: But I need this answer to pass my test case

Comment: Test cases should not be be checking floating point values for equality (unless you are actually testing the quality of floating point arithmetic).

Comment: Okay, double worked.